Why is the footer of Stack Overflow different from the other SE main sites?
Stack Overflow's footer looks like this:

Whereas the footer of most - if not all of the other - main SE sites looks as follows:
(I've checked 30-some and haven't found any other exception)

Is there an explanation for this, or is it just for historical reasons?
I'm aware you can reach the Tour and Feedback from the menu at the top right. But having to navigate SO differently seems odd to me.

Probably because Teams, Advertising, Collectives and Talent are specifically Stack-Overflow-branded. So it makes sense to list them as "Products" on SO itself, but not on the general network sites - there they go under "Company". I have no explanation for "Contact" and "Feedback" though.

@Bergi yes that extra column makes perfect sense, but the fact that the left-most column is different does not.

Your answer is right here:

Stack Exchange uses IIS, SQL Server, and the ASP.NET framework, all from a single code base for every Stack Exchange site (except Area 51, which runs off a fork of the Stack Overflow code base).[62] Blogs formerly used WordPress, but they have been discontinued.[63] The team also uses Redis, HAProxy and Elasticsearch.

Source
This shows that Stackoverflow has a seperate code base from the rest of the Stack exchange sites. That means the implementation is different on Stackoveflow hence a slightly different look.
Remeber Stack Overflow is an old codebase dating back 2008. The next oldest Server Fault is using the same software as other Stack exchange sites hence the more cohesive look.

I think you're wrong about your interpretation of that statement. I read that as saying the code is the same on all sites, including Stack Overflow, except Area 51. Area 51 is based on an old fork of the code. There may be some things which are different for Stack Overflow compared to all other SE sites, just like there are some things that are unique to some other sites, but the base code is the same.

Even if we read this as "separate codebases" that doesn't actually explain the difference in the footer. The codebases can be different but the footer can be unified in look and feel between the different instances. Unless you're arguing that a) it hasn't been due to omission b) it cannot be the same due to technical limitations. Explanation b) seems very weak. Explanation a) seems hard to believe, either, since the footer has been updated multiple times to add more items in it (e.g., recent ones are Collectives and Cookie settings), therefore, the company is aware of different instances.
